# Remove class from body using Page Layout XML

Tags: magento2

I am overriding a page layout for the account page, and I need to remove the class `account` from the body because it is causing conflicting styles.

I am overriding the page layout `customer_account.xml` but what do I put in there to remove it.

It is originally added with:

```
<attribute name="class" value="account"/>
```

I initially tried:

```
<attribute name="class" value="account" remove="true"/>
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the layout file completely (not extend) by placing the overriding file in `<theme_dir>/Magento_Customer/layout/override/base/customer_account.xml`. This way you copy over everything except for the `attribute` tag.